# If $a, b$ are positive in a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a+b = 0$ are then $a$ and $b$ also $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The title already says most of the question (our definition of positive means self-adjoint and having a positive, real spectrum), but the reason I was wondering about this is because we just covered this topic in functional analysis and I was asking myself if this property holds in general besides just in the real numbers etc. It would seem intuitive especially when people use the notation $a \geq 0$ for positivity (even though it's a bit misleading in my opinion). Could someone give me some insight if this is true or if it has counterexamples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ is positive then $\sigma(a)\subseteq [0,\infty)$.  If moreover $a=-b$, with $b$ positive, then $\sigma(a)\subseteq (-\infty,0]$, by the spectral mapping Theorem.    Thus $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$, so the spectral radius of $a$ is zero, and hence also its norm.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for answering my little curiosity :)